# Unable to apply redirects and rewrites together in NextJS's config file

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js, url-rewriting

I have rewrites in next.config.js like so:

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
      
      {
        source: '/trainer/:path*',
        destination: '/TrainerProfile/:path*',
      },
}
```

And I need to do 301 redirect for an old route mapped to *'/trainer/:path*'* which then rewrites *'/TrainerProfile/:path*'*

```
async redirects() {
  return [
    {
     source: '/instructor/:path*',
     destination: '/trainer/:path*',
     permanent: true
    },
```

The undesired behavior is that *'/instructor/:path*'* redirects to *'/TrainerProfile/:path*'*

Comment: What would you expect to happen though? This behaviour seems pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: I want the resulting URL to be /trainer/:path* instead of /TrainerProfile/:path*

Comment: But you've got a rewrite there that changes it to that... I don't know what to say except remove it?

Comment: @catgirlkelly My page is called TrainerProfile.tsx. Is renaming it to trainer.tsx the only solution to redirect only and avoid rewriting?